# File corrupted by some tools (probably virus or antivirus)- does the pattern indicate any known corruptions?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

As part of our software we install postgres(windows).  In one of the customer sites,  a set of files got corrupted. All files were part of timezone information(postgres/share/timezone). They are some sort of binary files.

After the corruption, they all starts with following pattern

od -tac output

```
$ od -tac GMT
0000000 can esc etx sub nak dle  em   |  nl  em  so   |   o   r   l   _
        030 033 003 032 025 020 031   |  \n 031 016   |   o   r   l   _
0000020   \   \   \   \   \   \   \ del   3  fs   ] del del del del del
          \   \   \   \   \   \   \ 377   3 034   ] 377 377 377 377 377
0000040   > ack   r   v   s ack   p soh   q   h   r   s   q   w   h   q
        276 206 362 366 363 206 360 201 361 350 362 363 361 367 350 361
0000060   t   r ack   h eot   s   }   v   h   | etx   p eot ack nul   }
        364 362 206 350 204 363 375 366 350 374 203 360 204 206 200 375
0000100   |   q   t   s   t   8   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E
        374 361 364 363 364 270 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305
0000120   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E   E
        305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305 305
*
0000240   m   ;   z dc3   7 sub   c can  em   a   u   5 can   d   2   B
        355   ;   z 023 267 232 343 230 031   a   u   5 230   d 262 302
0000260   X nul   y   J   o   S   -   9   ] stx soh   L can   1   !   j
        330  \0   y 312   o   S 255   9 335 202 001 314 030 261 241   j
0000300 dle   g   o etb   n  ff  em   ]   9   F   ' dc4   }   ,  em   $
        020   g 357 227   n  \f 231   ] 271   F 247 024 375 254 231 244
0000320   Q  si  ff   L  bs   2   # stx   i   5   r   %   |   |   c del
          Q 017 214 314 210   2   # 002 351   5 362 245 374 374 343 177
0000340   m   C esc   H  em enq   ~   X   o   V   p   /   l dc3   N  sp
          m   C 033   H 031 205 376   X   o 326 360 257   l 023   N
0000360   }   ) enq   ( syn   !   3   s   $   E   z dc3   A dc3  ff   P
```

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading file to http://virustotal.com and look if some antivirus apprehend file as virus.

If you are using Windows, you may use [Sysinternals Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642) to check what program did modify it. As alternative, you may turn on auditing in Group Policy, anable auditing for file's folder and check eventlog.

What does unix `file` utility say about this file?

Comment: I do not have access to the real time modification. The corrupted data is with me. Checked with virustotal.com. Nothing reported, does not look like a virus.